# Compile an anonymous word in a compiled word

Tags: compilation, metaprogramming, forth

I'm currently working on a small interpreter written in Forth. For a small optimization, I'm trying to have a word which creates compiled words. For example, something which behaves like this:

```
: creator ( -- a )
    :noname ( u -- u )
        10 + ;
;

10 creator execute .
>> 20 ok
```

I tried several approaches so far and non worked (naïve like above, switching in interpretive mode, trying to compile a string of Forth source). Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write compiling words, you have to be very careful about which words execute at compile time, and which execute at runtime.  In this case, `10 +` runs at compile time, and will not be compiled into you :noname definition.

I believe this is what you want:

```
: creator ( -- xt )   :noname ( n1 -- n2 )
   10 postpone literal  postpone +  postpone ; ;
```

Also note that you may use CREATE DOES> in many cases.  E.g. if you want your `creator` to accept a number which is used by the child word:

```
: creator ( n1 "name" -- )   create ,
   does> ( n2 -- n1+n2 )   @ + ;
```

Comment: Thanks this looks quite promising. I'll try it as soon as I'm back at a machine with forth.

Comment: Maybe two helpful links I've found after experimenting with your solution:
http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.forth/lambda-+-currying-bigforth-gforth-question/1260723
http://www.forth-ev.de/repos/bigforth/lambda.fs

Comment: You may also want to check out ]] [[ macros (in gforth and possibly others).  With those, the code becomes: `: creator   :noname 10 ]] literal + ; [[ ;`